# Highlighting extracted keywords inside extracted description

Tags: php

Okay suppose we would like to get title,keywords and description of website so i'm going to use the following function

```
<?PHP

function getInfo($URL)
{
    $getInfo= get_meta_tags($URL);
    return $getInfo;
}

$URL = "http://www.my_site.com"; // URL

// Applying the function
$_getInfo = getInfo($URL);

// Print the results.

echo $_getInfo ["keywords"]."<br>"; // gives keywords
echo $_getInfo ["description"]."<br>"; // gives description

?>
```

Yet,everything if fine but suppose the results as following

**Keywords**

```
php,profitable,share
```

**Description**

```
Advanced profitable and featured script to share
```

As in this example we've some keywords found in description `profitable` and `share`

The question is how to highlight keywords that only found in description!!

I will add the following css

```
<style>
.highlight{background: #CEDAEB;}
.highlight_important{background: #F8DCB8;}
</style>
```

and will add this function to alter between two different colors just like in `css` code

```
<?PHP
    function hightlight($str, $keywords = '')
    {
        $keywords = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', strip_tags(trim($keywords))); // filter
        $style = 'highlight';
        $style_i = 'highlight_important';
        $var = '';
        foreach (explode(' ', $keywords) as $keyword) {
            $replacement = "<span class='".$style."'>".$keyword."</span>";
            $var .= $replacement." ";
            $str = str_ireplace($keyword, $replacement, $str);
        }
        $str = str_ireplace(rtrim($var), "<span class='".$style_i."'>".$keywords."</span>", $str);
        return $str;
    }
?>
```

**Now** applying both (Not working)

```
$string = hightlight($_getInfo["description"], $_getInfo ["keywords"]);
echo $string;
```

Why not working cause it define `$_getInfo ["keywords"]` as one word `php,profitable,share`
which indeed not found in description in that shape.

so **how can i apply it** by using `explode` or `foreach` (i guess) so the out put be like this :

[image]

I wonder if there was another way to do it if mine looks not good way. ~ Thanks

Comment: Are your keywords really a comma separated list like you show? If so you need `foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword)`

Comment: Oh my lord .. how stupid iam i made explode by space while it should be by comma @DigitalChris thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keywords are in list format you need to:

```
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword)
```